How to Solve "ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank."
I want to make object detection using tensorflow I already make the dataset, train the label, building the neural network, define the losses and optimizers, and currently i am in the stage of training the neural network and I get this kind of error:
ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.
def localization_loss(y_true, yhat):            
    delta_coord = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true[:,:2] - yhat[:,:2]))
                    
    h_true = y_true[:,3] - y_true[:,1] 
    w_true = y_true[:,2] - y_true[:,0] 

    h_pred = yhat[:,3] - yhat[:,1] 
    w_pred = yhat[:,2] - yhat[:,0] 
    
    delta_size = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w_true - w_pred) + tf.square(h_true-h_pred))
    
    return delta_coord + delta_size

classloss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
regressloss = localization_loss

localization_loss(y[1], coords)

classloss(y[0], classes)

regressloss(y[1], coords)

class PalmTracker(Model): 
    def __init__(self, eyetracker,  **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = eyetracker

    def compile(self, opt, classloss, localizationloss, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)
        self.closs = classloss
        self.lloss = localizationloss
        self.opt = opt
    
    def train_step(self, batch, **kwargs): 
        
        X, y = batch
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape: 
            classes, coords = self.model(X, training=True)
            
            batch_classloss = self.closs(y[0], classes)
            batch_localizationloss = self.lloss(tf.cast(y[1], tf.float32), coords)
            
            total_loss = batch_localizationloss+0.5*batch_classloss
            
            grad = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        
        opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, self.model.trainable_variables))
        
        return {"total_loss":total_loss, "class_loss":batch_classloss, "regress_loss":batch_localizationloss}
    
    def test_step(self, batch, **kwargs): 
        X, y = batch
        
        classes, coords = self.model(X, training=False)
        
        batch_classloss = self.closs(y[0], classes)
        batch_localizationloss = self.lloss(tf.cast(y[1], tf.float32), coords)
        total_loss = batch_localizationloss+0.5*batch_classloss
        
        return {"total_loss":total_loss, "class_loss":batch_classloss, "regress_loss":batch_localizationloss}
        
    def call(self, X, **kwargs): 
        return self.model(X, **kwargs)

model = PalmTracker(palmtracker)
model.compile(opt, classloss, regressloss)
logdir='logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=10, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

